# How to make bash execute a script every time it exits?

Tags: bash

I want to execute some commands every time I exit from bash, but cannot find a way to do it.
There is a ~/.bash_logout file for when you are logging out, but normally we use interactive shell instead of login shell, so this is not very useful for this purpose.

Is there a way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: ok, let me put it this way: i want a script to be automatically executed before I exit from bash in a terminal emulator.

Comment: A trap EXIT might work.

Answer (score 5):

You can trap the EXIT signal.

```
exit_handler () {
  # code to run on exit
}

trap 'exit_handler' EXIT
```

---

Techinically, `trap exit_handler EXIT` would work as well. I quoted it to emphasize that the first argument to `trap` is a string that is essentially passed to `eval`, and not necessarily a single function name. You could just as easily write

```
trap 'do_this; do_that; if [[ $PICKY == yes ]]; then one_more_thing; fi' EXIT
```

rather than gather your code into a single function.

Comment: You mean these should be put into .bashrc?

Comment: Ah, yes, I forgot to mention that.